# How can I edit a cell in my GridView if some requirement is true

Tags: c#, jquery, t-sql, gridview

I have a GridView with some columns. If exist a value in my database, a cell in my gridview has to updated his own value.

For example:

```
      1     2    
1 - Lucas   Delete 
2 - Drake   Delete
3 - Jimmy   Update/Delete
```

If Jimmy exists in my DataBase, then I have to put the "Update/Delete" in my second column, but if this "Update" label is clicked, I call a  javascript. How can I do that ? It can be done via Sql ?

My code-behind:

```
protected void carregaGrid()
        {
            Utilidade.QuebraToken tk = new Utilidade.QuebraToken();
            string Credenciada = tk.CarregaToken(1, Request.Cookies["token"].Value);
            string Proposta = string.Empty;
            string select = string.Empty;         

                select = "SELECT San_Proposta.Proposta_Id, San_Proposta.DataHora, San_Proposta.ValorProposta, San_Proposta.Comentario, "
                    + "San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_StatusProposta.Descricao, "
                    + "(SELECT COUNT(*) "
                    + "FROM San_PropostaConversa "
                    + "WHERE San_PropostaConversa.Proposta_Id = San_Proposta.Proposta_Id "
                    + "AND San_PropostaConversa.Credenciada_Id = San_Proposta.Credenciada_Id) as Numero "
                    + "FROM San_Proposta "
                    + "JOIN San_Credenciada "
                    + "ON San_Proposta.Credenciada_Id = San_Credenciada.Credenciada_Id "
                    + "JOIN San_StatusProposta "
                    + "ON San_Proposta.StatusProposta_Id = San_StatusProposta.StatusProposta_Id "
                    + "JOIN San_Usuario "
                    + "ON San_Proposta.Usuario_Id = San_Usuario.Usuario_Id ";

                if (Request.QueryString["Imovel_Id"].ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    string imovel = Request.QueryString["Imovel_Id"].ToString();
                    select += "WHERE San_Proposta.Imovel_Id = " + imovel + " "
                         + "AND San_Proposta.Credenciada_Id = " + Credenciada + " "
                         + "AND San_Proposta.StatusProposta_Id IN (1,2) ";
                }                
            }

            select += "ORDER BY San_Proposta.DataHora DESC, Apelido ";

            neticonn.Conexao c = new neticonn.Conexao();
            dsGrid.ConnectionString = c.Con;
            dsGrid.SelectCommand = select;            
        }
```

Comment: Off topic, you might want to use an @-quoted verbatim string literal rather than all those + operators on your SQL select string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an ajax request to check if your item exists in your database. Your script will return you a json with true if your request finds it, false otherwise.

The other way is to build a javascript array on your page loading and check on it if your value is present.

I don't know c#, but in php it will do something like :

```
<script>
var values = [
<?php 
foreach ($valueFromDatabase as $key => $value) {
     echo '"'.$value.'"';
     //Hack to remove the last comma
     if ($value == $valueFromDatabase[$valueFromDatabase.length - 1]) {
        echo ",";
     }
}
?>
];
</script>
```

It will make you a javascript array looking like :

```
var values = ["Lucas","Drake","Jimmy"];
```

You just have to loop on this array to check if an element exists or use a javascript function to do that.

Comment: But, in jquery, ajax or javascript. How can I do this function ? This will be my big problem.

Comment: My second solution (with code example) is not good for you? Build the javascript array on page loading?

Comment: i need something dynamic, because the names can change

Comment: So, you have to use ajax and make a script on the url called. You can check this : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  The url called have to return a json with true or false.